# Android AlarmManager RTC doesn't pause while device is sleeping

Tags: android, alarmmanager, sleep, real-time-clock

I wrote a little widget for Android devices.

The widget uses `AlarmManager` to set recurring updates.
I'm using the `RTC` clock for the `AlarmManager`.

According to the documentation, if the device is sleeping, the `RTC` clock won't wake up the device and the next update will be when the device is woken.

I have a log file for the widget which shows when it was updated.

Even when I don't touch the device , I still see updates in the log file.

Why is that? shouldn't the device be sleeping and thus my widget shouldn't update?

I'm using `System.currentTimeMillis()` for the starting time so it should be correct for `RTC` clock.

Comment: Maybe some other application keeps the processor in running state with a lock.

Comment: @Ran please check `/sys/power/wake_lock` via `adb shell` if it's empty or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowing the phone to sleep while using RTC alarm on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112327/allowing-the-phone-to-sleep-while-using-rtc-alarm-on-android)

Answer (score 12):

You need to disconnect device from your desktop. When device is charging it doesn't go to sleep mode even when screen is black.