# What behaviour should I expect from setting an AlarmManager.RTC type alarm?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make my widget update periods configurable through the use of the `AlarmManager`.  I've now got this working by implementing the `onReceive()` method in my `AppWidgetProvider` which in turn calls the `onUpdate()` method of the AppWidgetProvider when it receives a broadcast of my alarm.  This appears to be working, though I am still struggling to understand certain scenarios.

Last night, I configured the alarm to update every hour and to not wake the phone up.  As you can see from the out `adb shell dumpsys alarm` below, I've successfully registered a RTC alarm to execute every hour:

```
RTC #1: Alarm{40b354b0 type 1 com.my.app}
type=1 when=+59m40s6ms repeatInterval=3600000 count=1
operation=PendingIntent{40c11e70: PendingIntentRecord{40e2b290 com.my.app broadcastIntent}}
```

Anyway, I unplugged my phone, turned the screen off and went to bed.   In my `onReceive()` method, I output log messages to a file to ensure I capture what is going on.  This morning I took a look at the log and discovered that my onRecieve() method fired every hour without fail.  It never slept through a single alarm.

Why is this the case?  While I suppose its possible other processes or alarms are waking up my phone, it seems suspicious.  Can anyone offer any information or advice?

Finally, does anyone know what the `count=1` means in my output above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowing the phone to sleep while using RTC alarm on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112327/allowing-the-phone-to-sleep-while-using-rtc-alarm-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered at

[Allowing the phone to sleep while using RTC alarm on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112327/allowing-the-phone-to-sleep-while-using-rtc-alarm-on-android)

and is a common issue.

I don't know what count = 1 means though.