# About the difference between the alarms of type of AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP and AlarmManager.RTC

Tags: android, alarmmanager

What is the difference between the alarms of type of `RTC_WAKEUP` and `RTC`?

From the documenatation of the `AlarmManager`, it seems that alarms of `RTC` will **not** wake up the device if the device current is asleep, and will not delivered until the next time the device wakes up. 
But I found that the alarm of type of `RTC` will still wake up the device, so what's going on?

What I did is to change the type of `RTC_WAKEUP` to `RTC` in the `AlamrManagerService.java`, function `setRepeating()`, and then set an alarm of 3 minutes from now on, then check the device, you will find that it still could be waken up by the alarm.

Answer (score 5):

THere are other instances reporting [`AlarmManager.RTC`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC) seems to wake up the device:

- [`AlarmManager.RTC` doing too many updates on wakeup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081988/alarmmanager-rtc-doing-too-many-updates-on-wakeup)
- [Android `AlarmManager RTC` doesn't pause while device is sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565622/android-alarmmanager-rtc-doesnt-pause-while-device-is-sleeping)
- [Allowing the phone to sleep while using `RTC` alarm on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112327/allowing-the-phone-to-sleep-while-using-rtc-alarm-on-android)

Each time, the root cause is the same:

Something keeps the device awake (even though the screen is black).
Don't forget that a charging device (connected to power) isn't sleeping.