# PendingIntent scheduled using AlarmManager.RTC type is still invoked in the sleep mode

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Here is the code that I used to set an alarm for my widget:

```
 private static void setAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
    myIntent.setAction(AUTO_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 8);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 8000,
            pendingIntent);
}
```

but the problem is that even in the sleep mode, `onReceive()` is still triggered by the intent.

Although after using `setInexactRepeating` instead of `setRepeating`, the delays between calls get increased up to 1 minute in sleep mode, but that's still battery consuming.

Comment: `AlarmManager.RTC` should not invoke the device in the sleep mode! What should I have to do to avoid invoking?

Comment: what is Android OS versions and devices/emulators you are testing your code?

Comment: I think this answer will be helpfull for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11273193/810368

Comment: Are you sure there are no other alarms scheduled in your test environment?
The system can wake up due to other event and then fire yours since it is already up.

Comment: There is another alarm which will be triggered every 24 hour.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are setting the alarm to trigger 8 seconds after the Calendar's time, which you have set 8 seconds ahead of the current time .. so you are setting the alarm to trigger instantly.

I don't see any reason you need a Calendar here. The calendar is just used to track the time 8 seconds in the future here:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 8);
```

The alarm is created to trigger every 8 seconds here:

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 8000,
        pendingIntent);
```

The alarm continues to trigger every eight seconds.

I would try changing:

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 8000,
        pendingIntent);
```

To:

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 8000,
        pendingIntent);
```

If you continue having problems, then maybe the interval is the problem. Try changing `setRepeating()` to `set()` to see if that's the case.